# How to deploy Asp.net MVC4 websit with MSSQL database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

i develop a mvc4 website and attached sql database . i am new in web development i purchased hosting from 1&1 and don't know how to deploy my website with database. i also published my web through files system and upload that folder through ftp but problem still remains with database. Can i use my hosting database or i have to upload database files... Please Help.[this is my database provided by 1&1 hosting how to connect it with my mvc project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7YWE.png)

Comment: 1&1 Hosting is not the best hosting to host MVC websites.  I joined them for 1 day and the next day I switched to Arvixe.  The technical team are not competent enough to help.

Comment: Hi Nauman, you can restore your database via their control panel. Or if you have problems, you can upload your .bak to them and ask them to restore it for you.

@Auguste As I know they have serious problems. Are you OK with them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to script your database and run it on the server you are shipping to. also you will need to change the connectionstring . also you can publish using visual studio and it may be easier that way